# Service request with OAuth (Invalid signature error)

Tags: services, authentication-authorization

I'm making a service request(POST) with curl and OAuth signature.

I have created a signature with the following code:

```
$signature_method = new OAuthSignatureMethod_HMAC(strtolower('SHA1'));  

$consumer = new DrupalOAuthConsumer($consumer_credentials['c_key'], $consumer_credentials['c_secret'], array());

$request = DrupalOAuthRequest::from_consumer_and_token($consumer, NULL, $options[$op]['method'], $options[$op]['url'], NULL);  

$request->sign_request($signature_method, $consumer, null);
```

And added to the curl header the OAuth credentials.
The problem is that when on the server side the signatures don't match. For example on the server:

> rsXZTiGBRYU+8WjxfnxZQ1g3IPA=

and client:

> rsXZTiGBRYU 8WjxfnxZQ1g3IPA=

and because of this it's giving me an "Invalid signature" error.
I think it's related to some encoding but can't figure it out.

Anybody has any ideas as to what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

The solution to my problem was the way i was sending the signature in the header of the curl method:

```
$oauth_signature = $request->get_parameter('oauth_signature');

$header = array('Authorization: OAuth '
    . 'oauth_consumer_key="' . $consumer_credentials['c_key'] . '", '
    . 'oauth_nonce="' . $oauth_nonce . '", '
    . 'oauth_signature="' . urlencode($oauth_signature) . '", '
    . 'oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", '
    . 'oauth_timestamp="' . $oauth_timestamp . '", '
    . 'oauth_version="1.0"');
```

I had to **urlencode** the signature before sending it.